# Scala Lift how to run javascript function and store return value in variable

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

Now I have this code:

```
JsCmds.JsCrVar(nombreAlumnoActual, JE.Call("retornarNombre"))
```

`nombreAlumnoActual` is a string var defined in my snippet and `retornarNombre` is the name of my javascript function, which is this one:

```
<script type="javascript">

            function retornarNombre(){
               return document.getElementById("nombre").value.toString();
              }
 </script>
```

But when I debug my variable `nombreAlumnoActual` is `""`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things to try with problems like these is to do some debugging. Specifically, in `retornarNombre()`. If you're using Firefox with the Firebug extension, you can call `console.log()`. Or you can use the Javascript debugging. Make sure that the function is being called and that everything is working as expected in that call chain.

Another thing to try is changing `JE.Call("retornarNombre")` to `JE.JsRaw("retornarNomre()")`. Yes, it's pretty much the same thing, but you never know.

Comment: Hi Donald thanks for your reply. I tried using JE.JsRaw but didnt have luck...i execute my javascript code in the onclick event with an alert and the value nombreAlumnoActual is correct...im using google chrome..

Comment: In Chrome, you can use console.log(). To see the console, select the menu option View -> Developer -> Developer Tools.

Comment: Donald, i put an alert in my javascript method and it doesnt appead during the execution, so i think retornarNombre() is never being called, is there a special place tu put this javascript code?? i can show you my html now is this

Comment: <form>
    <div id="form" class="lift:mySnippet.formularioIssue?form=post">
    <legend>Datos Generales </legend>
    <Span>Nombre</Span> <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" readonly="True" />
    <Span>Descripcion del Issue</Span> <textarea type="text"rows="2" cols="2" id="descripcionIssue" value=""/>
    <button type="submit" name="botonAgregar" id="botonAgregar" onclick="">Agregar</button>
 <script type="javascript">
  function retornarNombre(){      
  alert("Entro");
  return document.getElementById("nombre").value.toString();}
  </script>
</div>
</form>